# convert mongodb output to csv issue with json object

Tags: json, mongodb, nested, cursor

I have the following query which pulls data from two collections and one of them has nested values. I would like to convert this to CSV. One of the approaches I've taken is to use cursor and add each field I need separated by comma, here's the query:

```
cursor= db.csv_import.aggregate([
 {
     $lookup: {
  from: 'EN',
  let: {pn:'$part_no',vendor:'$vendor_standard'},
  pipeline: [{
      $match: {
          $expr: {
              $and: [{$eq: ["$$pn","$ICECAT-interface.Product.@Prod_id"]},{$eq: ["$$vendor","$ICECAT-interface.Product.Supplier.@Name"]}]
          }
      }
  }],
  as: 'part_number_info'
     }
 }, { $match: {"part_number_info.0": {$exists: true}}
 }, { $project: {"part_no": 1,"part_number_info.ICECAT-interface.Product.@ID": 1 as test, "part_number_info.ICECAT-interface.Product.Supplier.@Name": 1, "_id":0}}
 ]).pretty();
```

output:

```
[{
  "part_no": "C28-00002",
  "part_number_info": [
    {
      "ICECAT-interface": {
        "Product": {
          "@ID": "344038",
          "Supplier": {
            "@Name": "Microsoft"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
....
```

Then I'm trying to do this:

```
 while (cursor.hasNext())
 {
     jsonObject=cursor.next();
     print(jsonObject.part_number_info);
     print(jsonObject.part_no + "," );
 };
```

this works straight forward:

```
print(jsonObject.part_no + "," );
```

I get the part number, no issues there.

and this:

```
 print(jsonObject.part_number_info);
```

returns:
[ { 'ICECAT-interface': { Product: [Object] } } ]

which is kinda close, I just need to access "@ID" under Product and "@Name" under Supplier, but not sure how. I've tried this:
print(jsonObject.part_number_info. 'ICECAT-interface'.Product.@ID); but getting a syntax error (I'm sure it's not the way to access the nested object..

What's the syntax to access nested objects within a cursor?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I ran this:

```
print(jsonObject.part_number_info[0];
```

and I'm getting (example below):

```
{
  'ICECAT-interface': { Product: { '@ID': '86366746', Supplier: [Object] } }
}
```

it's getting closer, I need the "@ID" and the Supplier @Name

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out:

```
 while (cursor.hasNext())
 {
     jsonObject=cursor.next();
     print(
         jsonObject.part_no + ","
        +jsonObject.part_number_info[0]['ICECAT-interface']['Product']['@ID'] + ","
        +jsonObject.part_number_info[0]['ICECAT-interface']['Product']['Supplier']['@Name']);
 };
```